# Should I be accepting or rejecting these tag edits?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707364/vrajs5) keeps adding [ore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ore) to questions about Oracle R. It seems to be a brand new tag (they say so in the summaries), and I'm not sure what it's about.

It might be valid, but it seems to be an abbreviation of Oracle R Enterprises.

Comment: FWIW, [I've prodded the editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881074/error-while-replicating-an-ore-tblmatrix-in-r#comment37520397_17881074) and asked him to stop, and directed him to this meta discussion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That tag is next to useless; the `r` and `oracle` tags should cover such questions already. As an acronym, it is ambiguous. At best, the tag should be renamed to `oracle-r`, or `oracle-r-enterprises`.

Between me and Frédéric Hamidi, the tag has been removed from all posts now. Please do reject such edits.

They also [plagiarised the initial version of the tag wiki description](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5088495), it was copied from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/r-enterprise/overview/index.html

Comment: I pinged the editor with a link to this question...